# " Error `data`must be a data frame" when trying to plot a graph

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to plot a graph that shows the number of transactions (y-axis) throughout a business year (days, x-axis). I am given the code however, when I input the command I get the following error:

*Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not a character vector*

For the sake of reproducing my error I attach the codes I used:

- To create the dataframe (dates ranging 2018-07-1 to 2019-06-30):

```
transactions_by_day <- seq(as.Date("2018-07-01"), by = "day", length.out = 365)
```

-The code I was provided to plot the graph:

```
ggplot(transactions_by_day, aes(x = DATE, y = N)) +
 geom_line() +
 labs(x = "Day", y = "Number of transactions", title = "Transactions over time") +
 scale_x_date(breaks = "1 month") +
 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))
```

I have really been trying all sorts of things but I keep getting the same error so I would appreciate any help.

Comment: `seq` does not return a data.frame.

Comment: `transactions_by_day` is just a vector with dates. Where does your 'N' (the y-values) come from?

Comment: @Roland With what command can I substitute `seq`? 
@mfindinge I'm following a template that provides some help with the coding for my specific task, and the full code from above is provided, however N has not been specified to be anything in the whole document but my guess is that N would be assigned to the nº of transactions for each day

Comment: Since I don't know what your are trying to achieve with that command, I can't say. I don't even know where `N` is coming from.  I can tell you that `data.frame` creates a data.frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments already say, `seq` does not return a data frame. To convert it into a data frame just use `data.frame()`. So in your case:

```
transactions_by_day <- data.frame(Day = seq(as.Date("2018-07-01"), by = "day", length.out = 365))
```

Let me know if this helps :)